# Select values within/outside of a set of intervals (ranges) R

Tags: r, subset, intervals

I've got some sort of index, like:

```
index <- 1:100
```

I've also got a list of "exclusion intervals" / ranges

```
exclude <- data.frame(start = c(5,50, 90), end = c(10,55, 95))

  start end
1     5  10
2    50  55
3    90  95
```

I'm looking for an efficient way (in R) to remove all the indexes that belong in the ranges in the `exclude` data frame

so the desired output would be:

```
1,2,3,4,  11,12,...,48,49,  56,57,...,88,89,  96,97,98,99,100
```

I could do this iteratively: go over every exclusion interval (using `ddply`) and iteratively remove indexes that fall in each interval. But is there a more efficient way (or function) that does this?

I'm using `library(intervals)` to calculate my intervals, I could not find a built-in function tha does this.

Comment: Are your ranges always non-overlapping and in increasing order?

Comment: I use library(intervals)  -  `interval_union()` to ensure my intervals are non-overalpping. This also seems to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence for the corresponding elements in 'start' 'end' columns, `unlist` to create a `vector` and use `setdiff` to get the values of 'index' that are not in the `vector`.

```
setdiff(index,unlist(with(exclude, Map(`:`, start, end))))
#[1]   1   2   3   4  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
#[20]  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44
#[39]  45  46  47  48  49  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
#[58]  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88
#[77]  89  96  97  98  99 100
```

---

Or we can use `rep` and then use `setdiff`.

```
i1 <- with(exclude, end-start) +1L
setdiff(index,with(exclude, rep(start, i1)+ sequence(i1)-1))
```

NOTE: Both the methods return the index position that needs to be excluded.  In the above case, the original vector ('index') is a sequence so I used `setdiff`.  If it contains random elements, use the position vector appropriately, i.e.

```
index[-unlist(with(exclude, Map(`:`, start, end)))]
```

or

```
index[setdiff(seq_along(index), unlist(with(exclude, 
                       Map(`:`, start, end))))]
```

Comment: What if `index` becomes a set of random, continuous numbers, e.g. `index <- rnorm(100)*1000`?

Comment: @Ant Instead of `setdiff`, we use the numeric index vector returned from `unlist` as `index[-unlist(with(exclude, Map(`:`, start, end)))]` or `index[setdiff(seq_along(index), unlist(with(exclude, Map(`:`, start, end))))]`

Comment: The issue is that, for example, an `index` value of 5.255 would indeed fall into my exclusion interval, but would not get excluded - your suggested solution only removes integer values. 
I think I made a mistake calling it a "index" and giving it integer values, when in fact, what I've got is more like a bunch of random numbers, and I'm trying to exclude those numbers that fall within particular intervals.
Your answer is correct for my question, it's me who did not cformualte my question well and perhaps oversimplified. This might deserve a different question, then.
Thank you.

Comment: @Ant Please post that as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that looks valid could be:

```
starts = findInterval(index, exclude[["start"]])
ends = findInterval(index, exclude[["end"]])# + 1L) ##1 needs to be added to remove upper 
                                                        ##bounds from the 'index' too
index[starts != (ends + 1L)] ##a value above a lower bound and 
                                       ##below an upper is inside that interval
```

The main advantage here is that no vectors including all intervals' elements need to be created and, also, that it handles any set of values inside a particular interval; e.g.:

```
set.seed(101); x = round(runif(15, 1, 100), 3)
x
# [1] 37.848  5.339 71.259 66.111 25.736 30.705 58.902 34.013 62.579 55.037 88.100 70.981 73.465 93.232 46.057
x[findInterval(x, exclude[["start"]]) != (findInterval(x, exclude[["end"]]) + 1L)]
# [1] 37.848 71.259 66.111 25.736 30.705 58.902 34.013 62.579 55.037 88.100 70.981 73.465 46.057
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
> index[-do.call(c, lapply(1:nrow(exclude), function(x) exclude$start[x]:exclude$end[x]))]
 [1]   1   2   3   4  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
[25]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  56  57  58  59  60
[49]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
[73]  85  86  87  88  89  96  97  98  99 100
```