# subset data by set of intervals in R

Tags: r, subset

I want to exclude values from vector according to a set of intervals.

Example data:

```
mydata <-  sort(runif(100,0,300))
mIntervals <- data.frame(start = c(2,50,97,159) , end = c(5,75, 120, 160))
```

**Solution1:** using simple subset() - not suitable - length of mIntervals may be quite big

**Solution2:** using nested for loops:

```
valid <- vector(length(mydata))
valid <- TRUE
for(i in 1:length(mydata){
 for(j in 1:length(mIntervals){
  if(mydata[i] > mIntervals[j,]$start & mydata[i] < mIntervals[j,]$end){
   valid[i] <- FALSE
  }
 }
} 
mydata[valid]
```

this solution is taking too long in R.

**Solution3:** function findIntervals

```
   require(FSA)
   valid <- findInterval(mydata, sort(c(mIntervals$start, mIntervals$end)))
   mydata[is.even(valid)]
```

**Solution4:** use somehow package 'Intervals', but there is also no suitable function (maybe interval_overlap())

Quite similar (but not identical) issue was discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503718/select-values-within-outside-of-a-set-of-intervals-ranges-r). But there are solutions for vector of integers, not for continuous variable.

I have no more ideas. Solution no. 3 seems to be the best, but I don't like it - it is not robust - you would have to check for overlapping intervals, etc.

Is there any better solution to this very simple looking problem? Thx

Real data: I have light intensity measured at some times (datetime, intensity). I also have intervals of datetime where the measuring device was under maintenance (start, end).
Now I want to clean data = exclude values measured during maintenance periods (efficiently!).

Comment: Does this do the trick for you? I'm not sure what output you are expecting, but wrote this based on what I could see. `mydata[mydata > mIntervals$start & mydata < mIntervals$end] <- FALSE` edit: had to be single amplesant

Comment: Modifying your `findInterval`, you could use `mydata[findInterval(mydata, mIntervals$start) <= findInterval(mydata, mIntervals$end)]`

Comment: @Bas : this will not work - mydata and mIntervals has different lengths and the result is not what I wanted. But thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [development version (1.9.7)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`, we can try `%anywhere%`:

```
library(data.table)
# %anywhere% returns TRUE if mydata is within any mIntervals, else FALSE
ans <- mydata[!mydata %anywhere% mIntervals]
```

This will include the endpoints however as `incbounds = TRUE` is the default setting. If you need to exclude the endpoints you can use the following syntax:

```
mydata[!anywhere(mydata, mIntervals[, 1], mIntervals[, 2], incbounds = FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you rearrange your intervals, you can use the `cut` function and then take out only the odd intervals:

```
NEWinterval <- c(2,5,50,75,97,120,159,160)
mydata[cut(mydata, NEWinterval,labels = F) %% 2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an Rcpp implementation:

```
library(Rcpp);
set.seed(12L);
mydata <- sort(runif(100L,0,300));
mIntervals <- data.frame(start=c(2,50,97,159),end=c(5,75,120,160));
cppFunction('
    LogicalVector inIntervals(DoubleVector v, DoubleVector starts, DoubleVector ends ) {
        if (starts.size()!=ends.size())
            throw new std::invalid_argument("starts and ends must be same length.");
        LogicalVector res(v.size(),false);
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            double val = v[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < starts.size(); ++j)
                if (val>starts[j] && val<ends[j]) {
                    res(i) = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
        return res;
    }
');
mydata[!inIntervals(mydata,mIntervals$start,mIntervals$end)];
##  [1]   6.863323  10.168687  13.765236  16.585860  20.808275  28.508376  29.355912
##  [8]  30.534403  33.809681  37.152610  42.659676  45.787152  46.319152  47.274177
## [15]  47.877135  49.281417  78.640425  79.475513  80.383078  80.814563  88.273175
## [22]  93.344382  94.136411  94.736104  96.603457 126.327013 130.399146 131.800295
## [29] 131.828798 137.282145 148.542361 151.430386 162.212264 162.541752 165.648249
## [36] 166.758025 167.388096 172.243474 172.603380 176.544549 182.477693 189.979382
## [43] 192.404449 192.499610 199.703949 200.945789 202.035664 208.173427 210.533571
## [50] 212.949140 214.431451 215.524016 224.951507 225.608016 229.180120 230.324658
## [57] 232.415456 236.278594 236.350904 244.164168 244.218976 244.669498 245.332560
## [64] 247.184695 253.110672 253.267796 263.339092 263.352697 264.826916 267.979469
## [71] 282.326263 282.786520 285.996158 291.379637 293.290767 294.260683
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how efficient this will be, but...

```
vbetween <- Vectorize(dplyr::between, vectorize.args = c("left", "right"), SIMPLIFY=F)
mydata[!Reduce("|", vbetween(mydata, mIntervals$start, mIntervals$end))]
```

Comment: This just hides the loop.. Also `dplyr::between()` doesn't allow open bounds IIRC (which is what OP seems to be looking for).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show another approach using data.table package using rolljoin.

First you melt and order the data frame of intervals:

```
mIntervals.dt <- data.table(mIntervals)
Intervals.melt <- melt(mIntervals.dt, measure.vars = c("start", "end"))
```

Order data and use roll join:

```
mydata.dt <- data.table(mydata)
setkey(Intervals.melt, value)
setkey(mydata.dt) 

final.dt <- Intervals.melt[mydata.dt, roll = -Inf]
```

Take only data with "end" value since you have used -Inf (merged with next closest value in mIntervals).

```
final.dt[variable == "end"]
```

Very fast and and flexible.